# jQuery setting attribute value issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I have some text boxes and on save , I am saving local storage data to them;

```
$(".formFieldUserData").each(function () {
  var key = $(this).attr("name");
  var value = $(this).attr("value");
  localStorage.setItem(key, value);
}
```

Now for some reason, even though I enter some value in the text box, `$(this).attr("value")` returns `undefined` always.

What is the issue ?

Comment: Can you produce a fiddle illustrating your problem?

Comment: Use `val` method. probably you want to listen to the `change` event too.

Comment: Do you have a label or other no input fields on .formFieldUserData?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You retrieve form field values using [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), not `.attr("value")`.

Answer (score 0):

This is your solution:

```
$(".formFieldUserData").each(function() {
    var key = $(this).attr("name");
    var value = $(this).val();

    localStorage.setItem(key, value);
});
```

**Note:** `"value"` attribute of your tag is changable, so you use the `$.val()` method to get it's value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".formFieldUserData").each(function()
        {
        var key = $(this).attr("name");
        var value = $(this).val();
        localStorage.setItem(key, value);
        }
```